# Element wise dot product of tensors in theano

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning, lstm

Is there a way to do an element wise dot product of tensors in theano. Suppose I have the following tensors:

```
>>>t1.shape.eval()
array([5, 3, 3])
>>>t2.shape.eval()
array([5, 3, 1)])
```

How can i do a dot product, so that each of the 5 (3*3) matrices of t1 get dotted with each of the (3*1) matrices of t2, to finally give me:

```
output.shape.eval()
array([5, 3, 1])
```

Both t1 and t2 are shared variables in Theano.

```
t1=T.shared(np.ones((5,3,3)))
t2=T.shared(np.ones((5,3,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you shuffle your second tensor, `t2`, along the 2nd axis (index = 1 because its 0-indexed), you could then use `theano.tensor.tensordot()` ([reference](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html)) to get the desired result.

```
>>> import theano
>>> import theano.tensor as T
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> t1 = theano.shared(np.ones((5, 3, 3)))
>>> t2 = theano.shared(np.ones((5, 3, 1)))
>>>
>>> t2_new = t2.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 1, 2)  # will have shape (5, 1, 3, 1)
>>> desired_tensor = T.tensordot(t1, t2_new)
>>> desired_tensor.shape.eval()
array([5, 3, 1])
>>>
```